# How can I create a n-m mapping table in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a table with a couple of rows and columns. The index/row of my table is a category and the in the last row of my table if have some ids. Is there a way to write the ids of the current column in every cell of my table that is not null?

Table(already in Pandas generated dataframe):

1               2           3          4           5           6                7               8

9  3161409      50342165   949138     NaN    147466     155307       NaN      3575062    
12 NaN        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
ids m90   v15   o1506   u55   m1701  m174   m90   m90

Lets say I want to have "m90" in every cell that is not "NaN". Is there a way to achieve this?

This is the desired output:

1               2           3          4           5           6                7               8

9  m90        v15      o1506        NaN     m1701     m174       NaN      m90    
12 NaN        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
ids m90   v15   o1506   u55   m1701  m174   m90   m90

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, can you be more precise in describing what is your input dataframe and what is your expected output? A sample of each of these could be useful in helping you

Comment: Hello, my input dataframe consists of 8 columns and 1250 rows shrunken down to three for simplicity sake. Expected output should be that the entire row with the index "9" should be replaced with the values of row with the index "ids". This should only occur when the values is not nan.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not very clear to me. I suggest that you edit your question by showing what your desired output should look like (even with only three rows)

Comment: I hope that my question is getting more clear with the edited question. Thank you for even bothering.

Comment: Thank you for being more precise. I answered you below, please check it out and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a small function that takes as input a `pandas.Series` and can be applied to each column of your dataframe.

I created this toy dataframe which resembles yours

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1': [123, np.nan, 'm90'],
    '2': [np.nan, np.nan, 'v15'],
    '3': [123445, 4, 'o1506'],
    '4': [np.nan, 23, 'u55']
}, index=[9, 12, 'ids'])
```

Then

```
def replace_non_nulls(s):
    # 's' is a series
    replacement = s.loc['ids']
    s.loc[s.notna()] = replacement
    return s

df.apply(replace_non_nulls)
#        1    2      3    4
# 9    m90  NaN  o1506  NaN
# 12   NaN  NaN  o1506  u55
# ids  m90  v15  o1506  u55
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been a headache for me for the last couple of days!

Comment: You're welcome! You see, just adding a sample input and desired output made the problem much easier to understand and reproduce :)